# How do I use a variable in a module that is defined in the main program?

Tags: python

I'm writing a program to control a camera connected to two stepper motors from a raspberry pi. I'm writing in python, and I'm having trouble understanding global variables (or names in python, I guess). I've looked up some things about scope and about global variables, but I'm really new to programming with python, and it doesn't entirely make sense to me. I have a program "MainProgram" that assigns a value to a variable, D_Alt. This program then calls a function from a module "stepper". The function needs to use D_Alt. I set D_Alt as a global variable in the main program, but I am still getting an error. How do I set D_Alt so that it can be used by the main program and the module?

Here is my code for the main program:

```
from astropy.io import fits
import os
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import math
import sys
import stepper

global In_Alt, In_Az, C_Alt, C_Az, D_Alt, D_Az

#start server and get initial position
os.system("indi.sh")
os.system("indi.takepic.sh %s %s" %(15, "InitialPosition"))
os.system("platesolve.sh %s" %("InitialPosition"))
stepper.initPosition()
stepper.initPins()

list_of_stars = [[0,0],[1,1],[2,2]]     #star in list_of_stars is [RA,D]
for star in list_of_stars:
    D_Az=star[0]                        #
    D_Alt=star[1]
    print D_Az
    print D_Alt
    stepper.moveMotor()
    for x in range(0,10):
        os.system("indi.takepic.sh {0}+str(x) .format(list_of_stars[star])")      #take pic with 15s exposure and rename with name of star and number
    stepper.resetPosition()
    os.system("indi.takepic.sh 15 ResetPosition")
    os.system("platesolve.sh ResetPosition")
GPIO.cleanup()
sys.exit(0)
```

This is the function from the module that I need to use:

```
def moveMotor():
    #move altitude motor
    global D_Alt
    result = D_Alt - C_Alt            #find number of steps to move
    if(result>0):                    #if number of steps is positive, move forward
        steps = result
        forward(int(delay) / 1000.0, int(steps), C_Alt)
        C_Alt = C_Alt + steps
    else:                            #if number of steps is negative, move backward
        steps = abs(result)          #steps must be positive, so turn result into positive number
        backwards(int(delay) / 1000.0, int(steps), C_Alt)
        C_Alt = C_Alt - steps
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Stepper_Motors/MainProgram.py", line 25, in <module>
    stepper.moveMotor()
  File "/home/pi/Stepper_Motors/stepper.py", line 149, in moveMotor
    result = D_Alt - C_Alt            #find number of steps to move
NameError: global name 'D_Alt' is not defined
>>>
```

Comment: The Raspi hasn't anything to do with your questions title.

Answer (score 1):

The `global` statement is a ***declaration*** which holds for the entire current code block. It means that the listed identifiers are to be interpreted as globals.

You still need to **define** the identifiers somewhere. This is the error you get: `global name 'D_Alt' is not defined`, you haven't defined the variable.

By defining a variable in the module root and not inside a function or other code blocks, you make it accessible to the entire module as *read-only*. However, to modify it inside a different code block, you need to declare it as global *inside that code block*.

Try this:

```
from astropy.io import fits
import os
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import math
import sys
import stepper

# Defining the variables
In_Alt = None
In_Az = None
C_Alt = None
C_Az = None
D_Alt = None
D_Az = None
delay = None

def forward(someArgs):
    .. your implementation ..

def backwards(someArgs):
    ..your implementation..

def moveMotor():
    #move altitude motor
    global D_Alt, C_Alt, delay
    result = D_Alt - C_Alt            #find number of steps to move
    if(result>0):                    #if number of steps is positive, move forward
        steps = result
        forward(int(delay) / 1000.0, int(steps), C_Alt)
        C_Alt = C_Alt + steps
    else:                            #if number of steps is negative, move backward
        steps = abs(result)          #steps must be positive, so turn result into positive number
        backwards(int(delay) / 1000.0, int(steps), C_Alt)
        C_Alt = C_Alt - steps


# start server and get initial position
os.system("indi.sh")
os.system("indi.takepic.sh %s %s" % (15, "InitialPosition"))
os.system("platesolve.sh %s" % ("InitialPosition"))
stepper.initPosition()
stepper.initPins()

list_of_stars = [[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2]]  # star in list_of_stars is [RA,D]
for star in list_of_stars:
    D_Az = star[0]  #
    D_Alt = star[1]
    print D_Az
    print D_Alt
    stepper.moveMotor()
    for x in range(0, 10):
        os.system(
            "indi.takepic.sh {0}+str(x) .format(list_of_stars[star])")  # take pic with 15s exposure and rename with name of star and number
    stepper.resetPosition()
    os.system("indi.takepic.sh 15 ResetPosition")
    os.system("platesolve.sh ResetPosition")
GPIO.cleanup()
sys.exit(0)
```

You can find more information about `global` here: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#global

Comment: The problem is that the moveMotor() function is much larger than I included because it controls two stepper motors (one for each direction). I wanted to put this function into a module to keep the main program simpler.

D_Alt is being defined in the for loop. I have checked that using the print function in the loop. I tried using the print function again in moveMotor() to see what D_Alt was set to when the function is called, and I'm still getting that error. The problem is that the value of D_Alt is not being read by moveMotor() for some reason. Is this unavoidable?

Comment: Putting it inside a module (or even as a class) is the right way to go. I would say making class methods and attributes would make it cleaner and clearer, with no need for globals, but that's up to you. Better naming conventions for your variables would make your code a lot more readable. (I like Google's style: https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html#Naming) As for the issue you've mentioned, remember you have to declare the variable as global in each context you mean to change it - so that means in moveMotor() and any other function you use. Otherwise it'll be readonly.